# Why is ArcGIS Pro so slow?

Tags: arcgis-pro, performance

I know this has been asked before, and there have been a lot of responses to this;

- https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/why-does-arcgis-pro-have-to-be-so-slow/td-p/599220
- [Redrawing slow in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/speeding-up-arcgis-redrawing-sooooo-slow/296287)

but I have spent days, if not weeks digging through all the responses with basically little evidential results or improvements. For this reason I am asking again, and bringing to the fore.

When using ArcGIS Pro I experience an awful lot of slow speed issues, including:

- time to take to click between ribbon tools,
- opening tools,
- running tools,
- panning through maps with minimal or no data on,
- folder operations,
- cancelling geoprocessing tools.

Please note:

- All data is local, except for the ESRI basemap. (it's faster without the ESRI basemaps but the software and ribbon use is still incredibly slow -  I don't even try to look at the Geography of Map layers in the Catalog view).
- All data layers are transformed on the fly to the Projection system of the basemap (WGS)- this is only a short term solution as it shouldn't be a requirement; people need to to work in a lot of other projection and CRSs.
- I have 60mbps bandwidth
- My machine has 16GB of RAM and is and i7-9850 machine; its specified FOR GIS.

Through testing it has to be the software because when I open the same data in QGIS, it's almost instantaneous.

I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Is your internet connection via wifi or cat6 ethernet? would recommend 32GB RAM for a workstation on a 64 bit OS. ArcGIS Pro does index your file/folders which can reduce speed. There are options https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/index-project-items.htm

Comment: Define "slow" please. Is your computer idle otherwise? Check the system monitoring.

Comment: Creating two new tags, one a mangled spelling of the product name, doesn't help get your question answered.

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting steps recommended here: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/3d-gis/3d-gis/troubleshooting-performance-issues-in-arcgis-pro/

Comment: @mapperz, this is a cat6 ethernet connection. Trying to minimize the issues that could cause speed problems (such as wifi). 32GB would be good but I use a GIS spec laptop provided by work. Thanks for the link to indexing. I will take a look

Comment: My experience is  different. For me, Pro is so much faster than ArcMap - startup, folder browsing (when adding data etc), rendering, geoprocessing and it is so much more stable.  The only time I find it slow is when using a layout with complex labelling, then it's a slug...

Comment: The second link you added is about ArcMap performance and that application uses an architecture which is 15-20 years older than ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: I have used AGPro in three different machines with similar hardware but video card. This hardware improved my ACPro experience significantly. I'm using now a MacBook Pro 2019 running AGPro trough bootcamp and works pretty smooth. This machine has an AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB video card

Comment: I have not seen the symptoms that you describe when using ArcGIS Pro on half a dozen laptops/PCs.  You do not mention the version of ArcGIS Pro that you are using but if its 2.7 then have you reviewed the [ArcGIS Pro 2.7 system requirements](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/arcgis-pro-system-requirements.htm)?  Does your machine pass the "Check your computer's ability to run ArcGIS Pro 2.7" test that is linked to on that page.  I think you should focus this question on a single symptom to see if you can develop a reproducible procedure for others to test,

Comment: My issues seem to be with individual projects. Pro a a whole works efficiently. But sometimes specific projects get unusably bloated and I'm not sure why. I can open the same data in a new project and everything is fine, but I've had projects that I've had to sacrifice because they couldn't do anything once opened.